# Why am I getting a method object not iterable error on an iterrows function?

Tags: pandas, iterator

I've gotten a bit of code to work, but when wanting the code to iterate through my pandas dataframe, it errors out.  The code is supposed to open and MPO image file and save it as a jpeg.  This works until I put the snippet in an `iterrows` call.

The error is as such:

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-21-30128a738cdb> in <module>
> ----> 1 for i, row in mpo_list.iterrows:
>       2     im = Image.open(Path(row['location']))
>       3     im.save('D:\\2018_Formost\\2018-12\\Photos\\'+i, format = 'JPEG')
> 
> TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable
```

Code below:

```
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path

for i, row in mpo_list.iterrows:
    im = Image.open(Path(row['location']))
    im.save('D:\\2018_Formost\\2018-12\\Photos\\'+i, format = 'JPEG')
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try `mpo_list.iterrows()` , brackets are missing.

Comment: yep. that's right.  If you want to put this up as a solution, I'll mark it right.  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome Jordan. Sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
mpo_list.iterrows()
```

Brackets are missing in your version.